# How is the joint proportionality (joint variation) equation (i.e. $y = kxz$) logically correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, ratio

If $y$ is proportional to $x$, and $y$ is also proportional to $z$, then how are we able to arrive at the equation: $y = kxz$ ?

My understanding so far of proportionality, which comes from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)), is that two variables are directly proportional if their ratio yields a constant.

Thus, if $y$ is proportional to $x$, then $\frac yx = k$, where $k$ is a constant.

So, if $\frac yx = k*z$, then how are $y$ and $x$ still proportional if $z$ is not a constant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does $f(a,b)$ being directly proportional to $a$ and $b$ separately imply that $f(a,b)$ is directly proportional to $ab?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322004/does-fa-b-being-directly-proportional-to-a-and-b-separately-imply-that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are directly proportional if their ratio is constant, *relative to $\alpha$ and $\beta$*.  That last phrase is missing from the Wiki article, because it is not relevant to the two-variable models discussed there.  But it is *crucial* here.

With that correction, direct proportionality tells us that $$\frac{y}{x}=\lambda_1(z)$$ where $\lambda_1(z)$ is independent of $x$ and $y$, but might depend on $z$.  Similarly, $$\frac{y}{z}=\lambda_2(x)$$ where $\lambda_2(x)$ is independent of $y$ and $z$, but might depend on $x$.  Dividing the two equations, $$\frac{z}{x}=\frac{\lambda_1(z)}{\lambda_2(x)}$$ or, rearranging, $$\frac{\lambda_1(z)}{z}=\frac{\lambda_2(x)}{x}$$

Each side of the latter equation is constant with respect to the other side, so let their common value be $k$.  Then $\lambda_1(z)=kz$, whence the claim.

Comment: This makes sense. Then is the definition from [themathpage.com](https://www.themathpage.com/ARITH/proportionality.htm) - **By whatever ratio one quantity changes, the other changes in the same ratio** - a more accurate definition of proportionality, especially when dealing with joint proportions?

Comment: @johnnyodonnell No, that definition suffers the same problem.  Let $x$, $y$, and $z$ be three mutually-related variables, with $x$ directly proportional to $y$.  Holding $y$ constant means $y$ changes with ratio $1$, so $x$ does too, so $x$ is constant.  But changing $z$ might induce a change in $x$.

Comment: That definition, too, can be corrected in a way analogous to on Wiki: "Assuming all else is held constant, if one quantity changes according to some ratio, the other quantity will also change according to that ratio."

Comment: In short, all these definitions describe how two variables scale with respect to each other.  In order to understand how two variables scale, you need to (temporarily) hold all other variables constant.